# Modal .close doesnt work on mobile phone

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile, modal-dialog

As is demonstrated in the fiddle below, closing out of the modal by clicking on the x in the top-right hand does not work in mobile. Attempts to search for answers on SO have come up fruitless. Any help would be great, as well as an explanation as to why this is the case.

https://jsfiddle.net/csapidus/f6z9f5eq/5/

Original Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

    <!-- <meta charset="utf-8"> -->
    <!-- <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> -->
    <!-- <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> -->

    <title>Padauk and Maple Brick-Style, Laser-Etched Cutting Board</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4304/35858762401_3288711c9e_o.png">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Covered+By+Your+Grace|Raleway:100,500,600,800" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Orbitron" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../style.css">

    <!-- <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->

    <style>

        * { box-sizing: border-box; }

        /* force scrollbar */
        html { overflow-y: scroll; }

        body { font-family: sans-serif; }

        /* ---- grid ---- */
        .grid {
            background: ;
        }

        /* clear fix */
        .grid:after {
            content: '';
            display: block;
            clear: both;
        }

        /* ---- .grid-item ---- */
        .grid-sizer,
        .grid-item {
            width: 32.55%;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }

        .grid-item {
            float: left;
        }

        .grid-item img {
            display: block;
            max-width: 100%;
        }

    </style> 


<style>
/******************** Image Modals ********************/

#myImg {
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg:hover {opacity: 1.0;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (image) */
.modal-content {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
}

/* Modal Content (image) Variation for Columns Page */
.modal img {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
}

/* Caption of Modal Image */
#caption {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ccc;
    padding: 10px 0;
    height: 150px;
}

/* Add Animation */
.modal-content, #caption {    
    -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
    animation-name: zoom;
    animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
    from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)} 
    to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}

@keyframes zoom {
    from {transform:scale(0)} 
    to {transform:scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
    color: #f1f1f1;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #bbb;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
    .modal-content {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

</style>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="footerU">
        <h1>Padauk and Maple Cutting Board</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="intro_unlim">
        <p> This padauk and maple brick-style, laser-etched cutting board was made as a shared gift for my parents (mother's and father's day). This is was my first experience making a cutting-board. The most severe trap I fell to was failing to apply enough wood-glue, which was caught early enough to not be a problem. After cutting, gluing, planining, recutting, regluing, and sanding, the cutting board was laser etched with a simple message, and then coated with mineral oil. + Cat Tax </p>

        <p> Estimated Building Cost: $65.00</p>
    </div>

    <div class="full">

        <div class="grid">

          <div class="grid-sizer"></div>

          <div class="grid-item">
            <img id="Img1" class = "modal-img" data-index = "1" src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/3/2847/34147175446_e7ebe5cdc4_b.jpg"/>
          </div>

          <div id="myModal1" class="modal" data-index="1">
              <span class="close">&times;</span>
              <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
              <div id="caption">pre-etched and pre-brushed cutting board on work desk</div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item">
            <img id="Img2" class = "modal-img" data-index = "2" src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4172/34699825346_be85d4d136_b.jpg"/>
          </div>

          <div id="myModal2" class="modal" data-index="2">
              <span class="close">&times;</span>
              <img class="modal-content" id="img02">
              <div id="caption">cutting board placed inside laser-cutter II</div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item">
            <img id="Img3" class = "modal-img" data-index = "3" src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4169/34355294230_9c84dc0d30_b.jpg"/>
          </div>

          <div id="myModal3" data-index="3" class="modal">
              <span class="close">&times;</span>
              <img class="modal-content" id="img03">
              <div id="caption">final product: etched and mineral oil brushed padauk and maple checkered cutting board</div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item">
            <img id="Img4" class = "modal-img" data-index = "4" src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4166/34358593900_22486937d5_b.jpg"/>
          </div>

          <div id="myModal4" data-index="4" class="modal">
              <span class="close">&times;</span>
              <img class="modal-content" id="img04">
              <div id="caption">3-D model with dimensions of padauk and maple checkered cutting board</div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item">
            <img id="Img5" class = "modal-img" data-index = "5" src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4182/34699822676_9bb2262b8d_b.jpg"/>
          </div>

          <div id="myModal5" data-index="5" class="modal">
              <span class="close">&times;</span>
              <img class="modal-content" id="img05">
              <div id="caption">cutting board placed inside laser-cutter II</div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item">
            <img id="Img6" class = "modal-img" data-index = "6" src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4194/33897860364_bfd67c08d1_b.jpg"/>
          </div>

          <div id="myModal6" data-index="6" class="modal">
              <span class="close">&times;</span>
              <img class="modal-content" id="img06">
              <div id="caption">Georgia Tech Biomedical Engineering Machine Shop laser-cutter software interface</div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item">
            <img id="Img7" class = "modal-img" data-index = "7" src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4167/34740177975_a70a99b992_b.jpg"/>
          </div>

          <div id="myModal7" data-index="7" class="modal">
              <span class="close">&times;</span>
              <img class="modal-content" id="img07">
              <div id="caption">cutting board post-etching, prior to being brushed with mineral oil </div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item">
            <img id="Img8" class = "modal-img" data-index = "8" src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4188/33931137563_c25cfc2718_b.jpg"/>
          </div>

          <div id="myModal8" data-index="8" class="modal">
              <span class="close">&times;</span>
              <img class="modal-content" id="img08">
              <div id="caption">final cutting board brushed with mineral oil and set out to dry</div>
          </div>

          <div class="grid-item">
            <img id="Img9" class = "modal-img" data-index = "9" src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4188/33931133583_4ebdbfe792_b.jpg"/>
          </div>

          <div id="myModal9" data-index="9" class="modal">
              <span class="close">&times;</span>
              <img class="modal-content" id="img09">
              <div id="caption">lazy cat tax</div>
          </div>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="return"> 
        <div id="button"><a href="../index.html">Return to Homepage</a></div>
    </div>

</body>


<script src="../jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src='../masonry.pkgd.min.js'></script>
<!-- <script src="../bootstrap.min.js"></script> -->
<script src="../imagesloaded.pkgd.js"></script>

<script>    
  // JQuery Method for Multiple Modals 
  $(function() {
    $('body').on('click', '.modal-img', function(event) {
      var $img = $(event.target);
      var index = $img.data('index');
      var $modal = $("#myModal" + index);
      $modal.find('img').attr('src', $img.attr('src'));
      $modal.find('#caption').text($img.attr('alt'));
      $modal.css('display', 'block');
    });

    $('body').on('click', '.modal .close', function(event) {
      var $modal = $(event.target).closest('.modal');
      $modal.css('display', 'none');
    });
  });

</script>

<script>
    // JQuery Method for Masonry
    var $grid = $('.grid').masonry({
      itemSelector: '.grid-item',
      percentPosition: true,
      columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
      gutter: 10
    });

    $grid.imagesLoaded().progress( function() {
      $grid.masonry('layout');
    });  

</script>


<div class="footerU2">
    <h1></h1>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: Just tried on my phone - it works fine. I used chrome 59.0.3071.125

Comment: Strange, I just tried on both Chrome and Safari, and it does not close upon selecting the x. I am utilizing an iPhone 6S